# A Cautionary Suggestion

Tags: knowledge, visual

Some pictures are worth a thousand words.
This one is worth just five.  What are they?

[image]

Comment: *(Well ... four, technically, but you're smart folks, you can figure out all five ....)*

Comment: Very clever... stupid puns.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Is it, noting today's date:

> Beware the IDEs of MarcH?